# How to Get Python's Pandas Dataframe Output on One Line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, terminal, output

- I have a program that is pulling financial information.
- When I run the program it spits out a dataframe that pushes the last column of the data frame to the next line.
- I want all the columns of the dataframe to be one one line.
- I have tried changed the Screen Buffer Size of my terminal to 200.
- I have tried resizing by terminal window.

Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import timeit

start_time = timeit.default_timer()

pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None


def getdata(stock):
    # Company Quote Group of Items
    company_quote = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/{stock}")
    company_quote = company_quote.json()
    share_price = float("{0:.2f}".format(company_quote[0]['price']))

    # Balance Sheet Group of Items
    BS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/balance-sheet-statement/{stock}?period=quarter")
    BS = BS.json()

    # Total Cash
    cash = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(BS['financials'][0]['Cash and short-term investments'])/10**9))
    # Total Debt
    debt = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(BS['financials'][0]['Total debt'])/10**9))

    # Income Statement Group of Items
    IS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/income-statement/{stock}?period=quarter")
    IS = IS.json()

    # Most Recent Quarterly Revenue
    qRev = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(IS['financials'][0]['Revenue'])/10**9))

    # Company Profile Group of Items
    company_info = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/{stock}")
    company_info = company_info.json()

    # Chief Executive Officer
    ceo = company_info['profile']['ceo']

    return (share_price, cash, debt, qRev, ceo)


tickers = ('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'T', 'CSCO', 'INTC', 'ORCL', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'TSLA', 'NVDA')

data = map(getdata, tickers)


df = pd.DataFrame(data,
     columns=['Share Price', 'Total Cash', 'Total Debt', 'Q3 2019 Revenue', 'CEO'],
     index=tickers)
print(df), print('\n')


print('Total time (Default Timer) = {:.5f} seconds.'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time))
```

Output:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dI0E.png)

Comment: `pd.set_option("display.width", 200)`?  I also tried `print(df, end="", flush=True)`  I don't know if those will work, but it might be worth a shot.  I'm using Spyder and all the columns print out in the interactive window without a break, so formatting is okay there.

Comment: Sweet Jesus it worked, well one of them did. I am working in Colab, which is where I got the problem initially and decided that I might move it to my terminal to see if that would fix my problem.

So, I tried the ```print(df, end = "", flush = True)``` and that didn't work for me, but the other one did.

 I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem!  I just happened to be fiddling around with different pandas options the other day and was curious myself. Cheers!